# Maximize Optimization using CVXOPT vs Scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, cvxopt

I have a code that use CVXOPT to minimize an objective function. At the same time I would like to adapt the code I have so that rather than minimize the function will maximize it.

I know this would be possible using Scipy. In Scipy to maximize the objective function with minimize you should set the sign parameter to -1. I was wondering if a similar solution or workaround was also available in CVXOPT. Is something similar possible in CVXOPT?

Comment: Just negate the objective. **But be careful**. Theory might bite you here -> convex vs. non-convex / global vs. local-optimization. Understand this first before proceeding. And you might get the idea, that your question is very undetailed. Therefore only these basic warnings!

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the issue behind (convex vs non-convex). What I am trying to do is maximise the vol/variance rather than minimise